# Write data to JSON file using for loop

Tags: python, json

My current sample.json looks like this

```
{
    "clients":[
        {
            "username":"user1",
            "level":"100"
        },

        {
            "username":"user2",
            "level":"200"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I add a third user in Python using the json library, so the file will end up looking like this?

```
{
    "clients":[
        {
            "username":"user1",
            "level":"100"
        },

        {
            "username":"user2",
            "level":"200"
        },
        
        {
            "username":"user3",
            "level":"300"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using this approach gives me TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'

```
import json

data= {
    "username":"user3",
    "level":"300",
}
    

with open('sample.json') as data_file:
    old_data = json.load(data_file)

data = old_data + data
with open('sample.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
old_data['clients'].append(data)
with open('sample.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(old_data, outfile)
```

of course, instead of `old_data` it may be better to use different name e.g. `json_data`, i.e. name that don't imply "not updated".